# Knockout Sending ViewModel as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, typescript

I am experimenting with Knockout with TypeScript and am trying to send a view model that contains another model as parameters to a function like:

TypeScript:

```
export interface IEmployee {...}
export interface ICompany {...}

export class ViewModel() {
    constructor(company : ICompany) {}
    public setAsOwner(parent : ViewModel, person : IEmployee) {
        parent.company.updateOwner(person.id);
    }
}

// In a different file
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(new ICompany()));
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: employees">
    <li>
        @*Employee details...*@
        <button data-bind="click: $root.setAsOwner.bind($parent, $data)">
            Set as new owner
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However I keep getting an error saying that `parent.company` is undefined. What is the right way to pass the view model as a parameter to its own function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`click`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding handler function automatically receives the current employee item as the first parameter, and if you call `$parent.setAsOwner` from a wrapper function, the parent view model is available to the method via `this`.

So change the `setAsOwner` method to:

```js
public setAsOwner(person : IEmployee) {
    this.company.updateOwner(person.id);
}
```

and the HTML to:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: employees">
    <li>
        @*Employee details...*@
        <button data-bind="click: function(employee) { $parent.setAsOwner(employee); }">
            Set as new owner
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```